# Console Application that doesn't read?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, console

I have a console application that listens for connections on a certain port using a `TcpListener`. I start the `TcpListener` but when I open my program the console immediately exists. How can I avoid it exiting while I am still doing asynchronous work?

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more about how your program works currently, and how you want to change its behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ManualResetEvent` to keep your application up.  Just create one, wait on it, and signal it in your asynchronous code when you want the application to close:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ManualResetEvent signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    //start asynchronous work
    //call signal.Set(); to close the application

    signal.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: I mean - My console does stuff but it exists immediately, but I don't want it to exit because stuff are still being done.

Comment: @user2714359 Then that means you're doing work in a background thread and have no foreground threads working.  Either do your actual work in a foreground thread, or have at least one foreground thread waiting for your background work to finish.

Comment: It shouldn't be the case, are you sure it's doing something when exits?

Comment: @VahidND If he's doing work in a background thread, and not in any foreground thread, then it would exit and kill the process.

Comment: @VahidND I'm listening for connections on a certain port using a TcpListener. When I start the TcpListener, the program immiedately exists because I'm not using Console.ReadLine. I want it NOT to exit and wait until I call exit from code.

Comment: @user2714359 Just create a `ManualResetEvent`, have the main thread wait on it, and then set it when you want the application to exit.

Comment: I guess you should use AcceptTcpClient(), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As the last statement in your console app, add:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: The the application *can't* end nicely.  He wants to be able to close the application gracefully when he's done with..whatever.

Comment: Oh, it sounded like it was a server that would sit there accepting connections forever.